# Hot to re-run a C++ code from a specific point in the middle of the code, after changing the code below that point?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

So, I have a program in C++ and I use visual studio 2010. My program is mostly procedural not object oriented programming though. The first part of my program does something, then the second half does something else that uses the information of the first half. The first half takes a while (~ 20 minutes) to run (I knew this through running it in debug mode and put a break point right after the end of that first half).

The thing is that I am experimenting different ideas for that second half. Now, whenever I write the code for any new idea, I have to run the whole code from scratch, and thus have to wait the 20 minutes before the new second half runs. This is very inconvenient/inefficient; since I will be doing this for a while. I also can not really write all my ideas at once and run different programs (with the same first half and different second halves corresponding to each idea) simultaneously, just because I get each new idea after I run the older one and understand somethings about the behavior of my algorithm.

So, is there any way I can start running the code right after the first part whenever I change something(s) in the second part, instead of having to compile it and run it from scratch each time I change something in the second part? And how is that, if possible?

Comment: Two programs, with the state saved in a file? The first half in the first program, run once, with data saved in a file. Then the second half is a separate program that reads the state saved by the first program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Visual Studio, you should look into [Edit and Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c.aspx):

> Edit and Continue is a time-saving feature that enables you to make
>   changes to your source code while your program is in break mode. When
>   you resume execution of the program by choosing an execution command
>   like Continue or Step, Edit and Continue automatically applies the
>   code changes with some limitations. This allows you to make changes to
>   your code during a debugging session, instead of having to stop,
>   recompile your entire program, and restart the debugging session.

But please pay attention to the limitations - [Unsupported Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dbey757.aspx), you might have to structure your code changes to fit within what's supported.